# how to parsing multiple json based on its index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i have a script like this

```
$scope.asd = angular.fromJson($scope.asd[0].jfk);
```

but it only parse the object only on index 0,i want to parse all object based on the index on only at index 0 .

my pseucode

```
var i = get index;
for(k=0;k<i){
$scope.asd = angular.fromJson($scope.asd[0].jfk);
}
```

how to do it in angularjs?

Comment: Please elaborate more clearly about your problem! Like by giving some example

Comment: Don't. Parse the whole thing `$scope.asd = angular.fromJson($scope.asd)` and then iterate over _that_ object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
var arr=angular.fromJson($scope.asd);
$scope.abc=arr.map(function(x){
   return x.jfk;
 });
//Now You can access all the jfk properties in $scope.abc like
console.log($scope.abc[i]);//i is the index
```

Or you can simply do

```
$scope.asd=angular.fromJson($scope.asd);
//And access properties like
console.log($scope.asd[i].jfk); //i is the index
```